# Why YouTube embedded code is not working on any smart phone like Samsung?

Tags: javascript, android, youtube-api, samsung-mobile

I'm using Youtube Embedded code for display my video on my website.to display this video I'm using Jquery plugin and and Youtube embedded code.

**Issue** My Video can't play or display on Samsung smartphone.

Here is my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var first_child = $(".url").first().text();
        $("<iframe id=videos class=" + first_child + " width=701 height=400 src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + first_child + "?rel=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>").appendTo('#video');
        $('ul#vurl li').on('click', function ()
        {
            var newname = $(this).children('span.url').text();
            if ($('#video>iframe').hasClass(first_child)) {

                $('#video').html("");
                $("<iframe class=" + newname + " width=701 height=400 src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newname + "?autoplay=1&rel=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>").appendTo('#video');
            }
            if ($('#video>iframe').hasClass(newname)) {

                $('#video').html("");
                $("<iframe class=" + newname + " width=701 height=400 src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newname + "?autoplay=1&rel=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>").appendTo('#video');
            } else {
                $('#video').html("");
                $("<iframe class=" + newname + " width=701 height=400 src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newname + "?autoplay=1&rel=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>").appendTo('#video');
            }
        }
        );
     });
```

This is HTMl for result after user click on my video

```
<div class="wrapper ">
        <div class="bg-gray">
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="data" id="video"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="data">
                    <ul id="vurl">

                        <li class="video_title"><a class="no">title </a><span class="url" style="display: none;">T1JbM8Oged0</span></li>
                        <li class="video_title"><a class="no">Kham New MV </a><span class="url" style="display: none;">AfBne0tKMCw</span></li>
                        <li class="video_title"><a class="no">Title</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">0ynW4eg70uA</span></li>
                    </ul> 
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The same it not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an HTML string as the selector.  Try using the element ID as selector, and appending the HTML string to it:

```
$('#video').append("<iframe class=" + newname + " width=701 height=400 src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newname + "?autoplay=1&rel=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```

Comment: Does it work with any other device?  Does the embed work if you hard-code it into the HTML?

Comment: Some of another device is work although samsung  But it not work on Samsung Galaxy A8.

Comment: I just mean try placing any YouTube embed directly into the HTML, without any jQuery.  So you can test whether the embed is the issue or jQuery is the issue.

Comment: What browser are you using on the Samsung phone?  Can you try on another browser on the Samsung?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97940/discussion-between-raduation-and-heng-sopheak).